# Why is Ikki so important for Genesis?

Tags: air-gear

I have watched *Air Gear* anime to a degree, and I have never read the manga (which always fleshes out the story more so the knowledge I'm looking for is probably there... I have not read or watched anything in months due to my job, and I probably will not do so for a long while yet, thus the question).

In the anime, Simca appears very early on. We know that Ikki likes her, which she uses to her advantage, but she is intent on raising him into the leader of *Genesis*. She succeeds, and I believe that is where I last left off, as I was confused as to why Ikki is so imperative to *Genesis* and indeed where *Genesis* even came from- it wasn't fleshed out much at any point before its reveal.

She says something about his innate talent, but what *is* Genesis and what relation does it have to Ikki?

Comment: well, telling you that, would be a major spoiler. so i recommend to read the manga.  i can tell you that it doesn't take long after the anime end, in the manga where all your questions are answerd

Comment: Gotcha. One of these days I'll go back and finish it then :)